# How to load Excel cell values onto empty textboxes in a tkinter GUI, after the file has been selected by and "Open File" menu and loaded?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, textbox, openpyxl

I have constructed a GUI with tkinter. There are two buttons, one to load an excel sheet and parse all cells and print their value. Also, I have a series of empty textboxes with headers. What I am trying to achieve is to load the parsed excel cells each onto a variable, then fill the empty textboxes with the cell value (i.e. the variable in question). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl

from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Define Window Geometry

main = Tk()
main.geometry("1024x768")
main.title("Window Title")

#Define Empty Cells to be Filled in by Excel File & Calculation

def OpenDataInputSpreadsheetCallBack():
    main.iconify()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "file_path_goes_here",title = "Choose Input Spreadsheet",filetypes = (("Excel 2010 files","*.xlsx"),("Excel 2003 Files","*.xls")))
    wb = load_workbook(filename = file_path, read_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if (cell.value==None):
                pass
            else:
                print(cell.value)
#
#
#Function to display empty rows and columns              
#
height = 5
width = 6
for x in range(1,height+1): #Rows
   for y in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(main, text='')
        b.grid(row=x, column=y)    
#      
# Define Buttons    

b1 = Button(main, text = "Open Data Input Spreadsheet", command = OpenDataInputSpreadsheetCallBack)
b1.place(x = 1,y = 120)
b2 = Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.destroy)
b2.place(x = 1,y = 150)
##
##
### Initialize Column Headers
Label(main, text="Header1").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(main, text="Header2").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
Label(main, text="Header3").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
Label(main, text="Header4").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)
Label(main, text="Header5").grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)
Label(main, text="Header6").grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=W)
###
# Define a function to close the window.
def quit(event=None):
    main.destroy()
# Cause pressing <Esc> to close the window.
main.bind('<Escape>', quit)
#
#
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show some **rows data** from your `xlsx`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

When I load the xlsx file and its parsed it comes up with the following (1st row ("League" to "Away") are headers, below the data I want to show in the GUI - the headers appear OK). This is a sample row, the complete xlsx has all fixtures of this football league.

League         | Date       | Home      | Away
Bundesliga   | 27.08.16 | Hamburg | Ingolstadt

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: What I am trying to achieve is to load the parsed excel cells each onto a variable, then fill the empty textboxes with the cell value

You don't have to use a `variable`, you can pass the `cell values` direct to the textbox.
For instance:

```
class Textbox(object):
    text = None

series_of_textboxes = [Textbox(),Textbox(),Textbox(),Textbox()]
# start reading from row 2
for i, row in enumerate( ws.iter_rows(min_row=2) ):
    series_of_textboxes[i].text = ' '.join(cell.value for cell in row)

print( series_of_textboxes[0].text )
```

**Output**:

> Bundesliga 27.08.16 Hamburg Ingolstadt

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1***
Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.